# Show filename at begining of each line when tailing multiple files at once?

Tags: tail

when tailing multiple files at once as shown below, is any there any way to show the file name at the start of each line?

```
tail -f one.log two.log
```

current output

```
==> one.log <==
contents of one.log here...
contents of one.log here...

==> two.log <==
contents of one.log here...
contents of two.log here..
```

Looking for something like

```
one.log: contents of one.log here...
one.log: contents of one.log here...
two.log: contents of two.log here...
two.log: contents of two.log here...
```

Comment: You can look at the `-v` (verbose) option for tail . This may not exactly match your ask, but is a start.

Comment: multitail can do this I think

Answer (score 13):

## Short answer

[GNU Parallel](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/) has a set of nice options which make it really easy to do such things:

```sh
parallel --tagstring "{}:" --line-buffer tail -f {} ::: one.log two.log
```

The output would be:

```
one.log:	contents of one.log here...
one.log:	contents of one.log here...
two.log:	contents of two.log here...
two.log:	contents of two.log here...
```

## More explanation

- The option `--tagstring=str` tags each output line with string *str*. From `parallel` [man page](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/man.html#NAME):

```
--tagstring str
                Tag lines with a string. Each output line will be prepended with
                str and TAB (\t). str can contain replacement strings such as {}.

                --tagstring is ignored when using -u, --onall, and --nonall.
```

- All occurrences of `{}` will be replace by parallel's arguments which, in this case, are log file names; i.e. `one.log` and `two.log` (all arguments after `:::`).
- The option `--line-buffer` is required because the output of a command (e.g. `tail -f one.log` or `tail -f two.log`) would be printed if that command is finished. Since `tail -f` will wait for file growth, it is required to print the output on line basis which `--line-buffer` does so. Again from `parallel` [man page](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/man.html#NAME):

```
--line-buffer (alpha testing)
                Buffer output on line basis. --group will keep the output
                together for a whole job. --ungroup allows output to mixup with
                half a line coming from one job and half a line coming from
                another job. --line-buffer fits between these two: GNU parallel
                will print a full line, but will allow for mixing lines of
                different jobs.
```

Answer (score 9):

```
tail  -f ...your-files | 
    awk '/^==> / {a=substr($0, 5, length-8); next}
                 {print a":"$0}'
```

---

\thanks{don_cristti}

Comment: @don_crissti, thank you! (1) a vs file -- no more wine to my glass! (2) good idea. I start to do something like this but I lasily said to my self "no one will make tail -f of files with spaces" :) -- I will use your excellent suggestions.

Comment: can you explain length-8? why it is 8 here, I know only 8 works.

Comment: tail -n 1 *.txt | awk '/^==>/ {a=substr($0, 5, length-8); next} {print a,$1}' | awk '$2>0 {if ($2 !~/chrY/) print $1}' | xargs -I {} qsub {}

Comment: @ShichengGuo,  8 = length("==> ")+length(" <==")

Comment: @ShichengGuo, Are planning a massive cluster job submission? -- good :) !

Comment: surprisingly/amazingly your joojoo magic `awk` solution works!

Comment: Explanation of the magic numbers: `tail -f` includes filenames output in the format: `==> filename <==\n`. So, in the `substr` function, the `5` removes the `==> ` and the `length-8` removes the ` <==\n`.

Comment: With a slight modification, this command pairs nicely with `logtop` to show the number of lines written per second to each log file: `tail  -f * | awk '/^==> / {a=substr($0, 5, length-8); next} {print a}' | logtop`

Answer (score 3):

If `tail` is not mandatory, you can use `grep` to achieve this:

```
grep "" *.log
```

This will print the filename as the prefix of each output line.

Output breaks if `*.log` expands to only one file. In this regard:

```
grep '' /dev/null *.log
```

Comment: I need to show file name in output of `tail -f` not `grep`.

Comment: @serenesat this would just print the entire contents of the files wouldn't it? The OP was asking for the filename to be printed when tail is specified

Comment: you can also just do `--with-filename` or `-H` to always force filename prepend.

Comment: i really love this answer! does exactly EXACTLY what is needed with a solution that is like 13 characters long. as opposed to tricky `awk` solution or `parallel` which isn't installed.

Comment: only problem is that if your logfiles are 1 million lines long. then your grep will spam 1 million lines to console (or over ssh)...

Comment: `tail -f` keeps printing the contents of a file as they are added. Your solution does not really answer the question because `grep` will exit as soon as it's done, i.e. it will only print the _current_ contents of a file.

Comment: Rather than the `/dev/null` kludge, use `grep -H`.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`multitail`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/multitail)

```text
multitail -N 1 --mergeall --label "one.log: " one.log --label "two.log: " two.log
```

Comment: Thanks @Stéphane Chazelas but your suggested code snippet causes the shell instance to exit and adds global variable `file`. Please remove the `exec` and make `file` local.

Comment: No. The body of the function was a subshell which is how you get local variables in standard sh

Answer (score 0):

My idea would be to create a single file with merged logs from several files, like someone suggested [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/47353/72304) and prepend filenames:

```
$ tail -f /var/log/syslog | sed -u -E 's,(^.+$),/var/log/syslog: \1,g' >> /tmp/LOG &&
$ tail -f /var/log/Xorg.0.log | sed -u -E 's,(^.+$),/var/log/Xorg.0.log: \1,g' >> /tmp/LOG &&
$ tail -f /tmp/LOG
```

Answer (score 0):

Something with `xargs` and `sed` could work:

```
$ xargs -I% -P0 sh -c "tail -f % | sed s/^/%:/g" <<EOT
one.log
two.log
EOT
```